# Which method is better for Search Engine Optimization (SEO)?

Tags: php, html, css, seo

The function I'd like to implement is: 
Click an image and go to a link. There are 2 methods:

1. Use onclick event:

   ```
   <div onclick="location.href='http://picask.net/';"><img src="logo.jpg"></div>
   ```
2. Use a tag:

   ```
   <a href="http://picask.net/"> <img src="logo.jpg"> </a>
   ```

The first method hides the link in the onclick event. The second one explicitly put it in an 'a' tag. Which one is better in terms of SEO? Or they are just the same? 
Thanks. Please explain why.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO, not about programming - see [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What happens if the client browser's javascript function is disabled? I think you should avoid javascript as much as possible, only use it for some advanced enhancements such as annimation, client validation, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Google now does execute Javascript - see [this link](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.at/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html). Still, the following largely applies, and I've made edits where necessary.

If you want search engines to follow the link, don't hide it. Search engines cannot/will not *always* execute your Javascript. Google does now, and others will follow, but the implementation is still experimental and might not work in all cases, so I would not rely on it.

But more importantly: why would you go through the troubles of writing Javascript, if having an `a` tag is better portable, shorter, easier..

If it was your goal to hide the link, you can either add the target to `robots.txt`, or add the attribute `rel="nofollow"` to the link. This will tell search engines your intentions, and they *should* obey them (at least the most important ones will). It's no reliable way to completely block information from being indexed, though, and it's mainly for reducing traffic and eating in on the page ranks of other pages on your own site, and it's useful for SEO as well.

Apart from SEO, it can't hurt to make your website work without Javascript in a normal browser as well. And if, for whatever reason, you want this link to work only when there is Javascript, there is also the possibility to insert the `A` elements using Javascript. That way, the document is still semantically correct, and that will undoubtedly be better for Javascript-empowered web crawlers too. Because keep in mind that Google will index the page as it is rendered. Previously, it indexed it's raw output, and now it indexes the document as it is after scripts have executes. Indexing could actually get worse if your scripts behave badly, for instance when they remove elements.

Comment: Yes indeed. That onclick event handler is a tiny piece of Javascript, and it's not executed by search engines, so they see just a div and nothing more.

Comment: So the link inside a JS event will be ignored by search engine?

Comment: I see people have updated my answer, because the original one would be obsolete. I think that is not entirely true. Google's execution of Javascript still feels pretty experimental and there are quite some situations in which they cannot execute it. Also, Google isn't the only search engine. And Google executing Javascript is something to take into account as well. The problems won't be magically solved, and actually, your page might be indexed *worse* once Google starts executing your scripts. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Additions? Please comment instead of rewriting my answer.